# Set partition, partition into X set with Y elements.

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

How do you partition a set into X number of new sets all that have Y elements?

Example: How to partition 18 unique cards are divided to six persons, and each person gets 3 cards each. How many combinations are there?

Answer (score 0):

This is the number of permutations of 18 elements, divided 6 times by the number of permutations of 3 elements.